# Change Menu Option Color Depending on the HTML File Loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I want to change the menu color of depending on the page loaded. I know this is very simple with the support of a server side language but this is a HTML  project i am into. So I decided to get the name of HTML file being loaded and act accordingly , but I am facing a strange problem in this approach. Let me explain.

**My Menu :**

```
      <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="menu-option" id="about" href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a class="menu-option" id="trainer" href="#">Trainer / Consultant</a></li>
                <li><a class="menu-option" id="testimonial" href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                <li><a class="menu-option" id="programs" href="#">Programs</a></li>
                <li><a class="menu-option" id="contact" href="#">Contact us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

**The JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("header").load("includes/header.html");
    $("footer").load("includes/footer.html");
    var page = location.pathname.split("/").slice(-1);
    switch (page[0])
    {
        case "about.html":
            $(".menu-option").css('color', 'white');
            $("#about").css('color', '#E45C02');
            break;
        case "trainer.html":
            $(".menu-option").css('color', 'white');
            $("#trainer").css('color', '#E45C02');
            break;
        case "programs.html":
            $(".menu-option").css('color', 'white');
            $("#programs").css('color', '#E45C02');
            break;
        case "testimonial.html":
            $(".menu-option").css('color', 'white');
            $("#testimonial").css('color', '#E45C02');
            break;
        case "contact.html":
            $(".menu-option").css('color', 'white');
            $("#contact").css('color', '#E45C02');
        default:
            $(".menu-option").css('color', 'white');
            break;
    }


});
```

Using Firebug I can see that the case is being invoked but the color of about was not effected. So I decided to add an alert in the about case

```
case "about.html":
            alert("about");
            $(".menu-option").css('color', 'white');
            $("#about").css('color', '#E45C02');
            break;
```

And this thing works as expected. I am really perplexed with this. Why does the code fail without the alert statement? What role is it playing? What m I missing here? do I need a timeout here?

I also tried to put the switch case inside a

```
$("header").ready(function(){
// Switch case here
// Still no luck !
});
```

Comment: Try to replace `$(document).ready` with `$(window).load`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but probably needs more time to render the `#about`. If `#about` not exists when the javascript executes, then no styles has been modified.

Comment: you forgot to write `break;` after `case "contact.html":` i think that might be the issue

Comment: But, there's something that i can understand. You don't want to use server code to apply this styles, ok, i get it, but why on earth don't you use CSS?

Comment: @frikinside Yes that's what I am doubting , yes it can be done , all I have to is add a class in the body for each page and I am done. But I wanna experiment with this method. And now since it's being naughty I wanna know y?

Comment: @Genocide_Hoax there is not an absolute right answer. First of all, I had a personal rule. Don't do with javascript what you can accomplish with CSS. And in second place, if you had this rules on the css, you will not have any problems with ajax content loaded, the webengine of the browser it will take care of it. But i don't see nothing precisly "wrong" with doing it with javascript, but I think is better for permorfance, usability and accesibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because .load() is asyncronous which means you need wait until the load has completed before taking any action relying on the loaded data.

You can send in a function to run as a second argument to .load(), which will be called once the data is loaded. Then you can run the switch statement in that function.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function onHeaderLoaded() {
        var page = location.pathname.split("/").slice(-1);
        switch (page[0])
        {
            case "about.html":
                $(".menu-option").css('color', 'white');
                $("#about").css('color', '#E45C02');
                break;
            case "trainer.html":
                $(".menu-option").css('color', 'white');
                $("#trainer").css('color', '#E45C02');
                break;
            case "programs.html":
                $(".menu-option").css('color', 'white');
                $("#programs").css('color', '#E45C02');
                break;
            case "testimonial.html":
                $(".menu-option").css('color', 'white');
                $("#testimonial").css('color', '#E45C02');
                break;
            case "contact.html":
                $(".menu-option").css('color', 'white');
                $("#contact").css('color', '#E45C02');
            default:
                $(".menu-option").css('color', 'white');
                break;
        }

    }

    $("header").load("includes/header.html", onHeaderLoaded);
    $("footer").load("includes/footer.html");

});
```

Comment: The menu is in the header? If that's true (what's makes sense) you're completly right, if not, there something else happening

Comment: yes , this makes sense. and @frikinside yes the menu is in the header. Thanks